# how i can write following equation in the matlab? its related to VSC HVDC system

Tags: matlab, controller

i want to write equation shown in the picture? its related to VSC HVDC system. how i can write 1/s in the equation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of `s`? A symbolic variable, a number, ...?

Answer (score 0):

The posted equations seems to describe two controller in the complex frequency domain. As stated under this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) explaining the "tf" function of the Control System Toolbox: to use a rational expression to create a transfer function model, first specify s as a tf object.

```
s = tf('s');
```

Create a transfer function using s in a rational expression (e. g.)

```
H = s/(s^2 + 2*s + 10);
```